# PC Power consumption: what if i downclock cpu?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

I'm thinking to downclock my home PC, to lower power consumption.
I found a BIOS option: CPU clock multiplier .. it was auto, i switched to 20x .
Before my cpu was clocked at 3.2ghz, now a 2ghz.

It is a Ryzen 5 3600.

Do you think i'm saving Watt ?

Thanks

Comment: No, not really but this is just a non-engineer's opinion.

Comment: Power consumption is CPU, motherboard, GPU, Memory, FAN and any other peripherals. Hook up a Wattmeter, measure, change options, measure again.

Comment: I would assume that the effect of downclocking the CPU is not that high unless you also undervolt it. But unually power saving is a task best performed before buying a PC. That is done by comparing the power consumption of the different components in idle and use state.

Comment: what would be more effective: a) limit processes running in the background b) close programs when not in use c) lower screen brightness d) disable animations and graphic effects in windows e) optimize your power plan, especially shorten the times for screen going dark, sleep mode, hibernation mode.